# How do I make a post answer non-caps sensitive, or have multiple answers?

Tags: php

How do I make a post have multiple answers?  And it would also be helpful if I could figure out how to make it non-caps sensitive.

Here is an example:

```
$a = "What is the color of the sky?"

if($_POST['ans'] == "blue")  {
   echo "Correct!";
}
```

form:

```
<form method="POST" action="">
<input type="text" name="ans" /><br />
<input type="submit" />
</form>
```

I have tried

```
if($_POST['ans'] == "blue" . "Blue")  {
   echo "Correct!";
}
```

And

```
if($_POST['ans'] == "blue" or "Blue")  {
       echo "Correct!";
}
```

Comment: @relentless How will checkboxes help?

Comment: @relentless  That's not what I need though.

Comment: @LegoStormtroopr checkboxes allow for multiple selections

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do the case-insensitive string comparison in PHP by using [strcasecmp](https://www.php.net/strcasecmp).

```
<?php
    if (strcasecmp($_POST['ans'], 'blue') == 0) {
        echo 'Correct!';
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [strtolower](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtolower.php) which turns all string to lower case, so bLuE will be blue

```
<?php
    if (strtolower($_POST['ans'] == 'blue')) {
        echo 'Correct!';
    }
?>
```